# Send Exported PDF as Attachment in Email

Tags: vb.net, email, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I am trying to send PDF as attachment in mail but I am struggling to find out what should be the path. I learned to Export Crystal Report in PDF Format but I dont know how to give the path in the attachment:

This is how I am Exporting PDF

```
Dim rptDocument As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
rptDocument.Load(mReportPath)
Dim exportOpts As ExportOptions = New ExportOptions()
Dim pdfOpts As PdfRtfWordFormatOptions = ExportOptions.CreatePdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = pdfOpts
rptDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(exportOpts, Response, True, "")
```

And this is the code to send pdf via email:

```
Dim msg As New MailMessage()
msg.From = New MailAddress("proccoinvoice@gmail.com")
msg.[To].Add(recipient)
msg.Subject = "Procco Invoice"
msg.Body = "Invoice attached"
msg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(filepath)) //Path should be given here
Dim client As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
client.Port = 25
client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("proccoinvoice@gmail.com", "<Procco>;1947")
client.EnableSsl = True
client.Send(msg)
```

My question is How do I give path of the PDF that is generated at runtime in the attachment?

Comment: is it windows app or web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the PDF file into `byte[]` to send as a attachment in mail.

Please check below code.

```
byte[] pdfarry = null;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  document.Save(ms, false);
  document.Close();

  pdfarry = ms.ToArray();
}


mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pdfarry, "testPDF.pdf", "application/pdf"));

smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxxx");
smtpUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxx", xxx");
smtpClient.Credentials = smtpUserInfo;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```